# Access errors in Symfony2 controller for AJAX submitted form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

**Problem 1**

I'd like to build a registration form via ajax submission. Registration works is the `$form->isValid()`. However, if the form fails registration I need to return these errors via ajax.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

}else{
    $errors = $form->getErrors();
    // return some json encoded errors here
}
```

`$form->getErrors()` returns an empty array even though the form did not validate (in this case I am testing with a username that is too short).

**Problem 2**

The second problem I have is that if the form validates but there is still an error. For example a unique field that someone tries to submit the same value for.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($form->getData());
    $em->flush();

    // error could be a username submitted more than once, username is unique field

}else{
    // ...
}
```

How can I catch that error and return it via json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem 1

In your form builder you can use `error_bubbling` to move the errors into your form object. When you specify the field, pass it in as an option like this:

```
$builder->add('username','text', array('error_bubbling'=>true));
```

and you can access errors in your form object like this:

```
$form->getErrors();
```

Outputs something like

```
array (
  0 => 
  Symfony\Component\Form\FormError::__set_state(array(
     'messageTemplate' => 'Your username must have at least {{ limit }} characters.',
     'messageParameters' => 
    array (
      '{{ value }}' => '1',
      '{{ limit }}' => 2,
    ),
  )),
) [] []
```

fyi: If you are using Form/Type's you can't set `error_bubbling` as a default value, it has to be assigned to each field.

Useful link: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

## Problem 2

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Answer (score 4):

## Problem 1

The errors aren't on the form itself. `Form::getErrors` would only return errors if there were any on the form object itself. You need to traverse the form and check for errors on each child.

`Form::isValid` on the contrary just traverses the children and check if any of them are invalid.

## Problem 2

If there still are "errors" after validation, that means that your validation isn't complete. If your application requires a non-standard constraint, you should just go ahead and write a custom constraint. See [the cookbook entry on  writing custom validator constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)  for more information.

Comment: How would the validator know that someone already has used that username in the table? I thought the validator checked if that data is correct, not whether that data already exists, or does it do both?

Comment: A validator can perform any type of validation you code it to do. Of course, as has been noted, there's already a validator for uniqueness, UniqueEntity.